# Configuring lidR catalog to overwrite raster output (with different extension)?

Tags: raster, r, lidar, file-formats, lidr

I have a small issue with configuring the `lidR` [package](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR) for parametrizing the extracted raster files with `grid_metrics()` function.

My question is how to set in the catalog options that:

1. be able to overwrite the results with a second run if I want to run
   my script several times and I do not want to name each output
   differently.
2. instead of `.tif` I would like to get `.grd` files as output.

My current code (which is working) is the following:

```
normalizedctg = catalog(workingdirectory)
opt_output_files(normalizedctg) <- paste(workingdirectory,"/clipped/normalized/{XLEFT}_{YBOTTOM}_height",sep="")
height = grid_metrics(normalizedctg, max(Z),res = resolution)
```

But with a second run on the same code I get the following error:

```
Error in .getGDALtransient(x, filename = filename, options = options,  : 
  filename exists; use overwrite=TRUE
```

Answer (score 10):

Your question is related to `LAScatalog` processing engine tuning. A topic not documented in the official documentation. The only one existing documentation at the time being (june 2019) is a [wiki page](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/Modify-the-LAScatalog-drivers) that provide an example to change the drivers.

In short the drivers used to write objects to files are stored in the `LAScatalog` object. You can access to them with regular R code. The difficulty is the fact it is not documented.

To save `.grd` instead of `.tif`

```
normalizedctg@output_options$drivers$Raster$extension <- ".grd"
normalizedctg@output_options$drivers$Raster$param$format <- "raster"
```

To force the `overwrite` option in `raster::writeRaster`

```
normalizedctg@output_options$drivers$Raster$param$overwrite <- TRUE
```