# grid_canopy with overwrite=TRUE

Tags: lidr

When I use this command :

```
> chm <- grid_canopy(gro, 1, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,15), c(0,1), subcircle = 0.2))
Processing [-------------------------------------------]   0% (1/341) eta:  8mError: filename exists; use overwrite=TRUE
```

I have an error because the file exist. How can i add the overwrite argument to grid_canopy because when i use this command :

```
chm <- grid_canopy(gro, 1, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,15), c(0,1), subcircle = 0.2, overwrite = TRUE)
```

I receive this error :

```
Error in grid_canopy(gro, 1, pitfree(c(0, 2, 5, 10, 15), c(0, 1), subcircle = 0.2),  : 
unused argument (overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configuring lidR catalog to overwrite raster output (with different extension)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325367/configuring-lidr-catalog-to-overwrite-raster-output-with-different-extension)

Comment: Also there is now a partial documentation here `help("lidR-LAScatalog-drivers")`

Comment: Yes this answer my question, thanks !