# Keeping name of metrics as band names when using grid_metrics (lidR)

Tags: r, lidr, grid-metrics

When executing `grid_metrics` for a normalized `LAScatalog` the final results are `GTiff` files where each band corresponds to a metric. The problem is that the band names are "band 01", "band 02", "band 03"... and I can not identify which band is which metric.
Is there a way to keep the name of the metric as the band name?
Here is the part of the script that I use:

```r
ctg <- readLAScatalog("C:/JAIME/dataLaS_test/", progress = TRUE)

# Load an extra buffer around the processed file to properly process the catalog without edge artifacts
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg) <- 10

# Write files to disc
opt_output_files(ctg) <- "C:/JAIME/00_tests/test2/{ORIGINALFILENAME}_normalized"

#Normalize LAS files
las <- lasnormalize(ctg, tin())

opt_filter(las) <- "-drop_z_below 0"

#export metrics
opt_output_files(las) <- "C:/JAIME/00_tests/test2/{ORIGINALFILENAME}_metrics"

#Create functionn to get metrics
get_metrics <- grid_metrics(las, .stdmetrics_z, 15.8114, filter = ~ReturnNumber == 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are describing is more or less an unexpected behavior. First `raster::writeRaster` does not preserve the names of the layers when writing in a `GTiff` format (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763013/r-write-rasterstack-and-preserve-layer-names)). So anyway you must change the default format (see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325367/configuring-lidr-catalog-to-overwrite-raster-output-with-different-extension/325369#325369)).

Then, once all the rasters are computed and written on disk, `lidR` uses `gdalUtils::gdalbuildvrt` to return a single object instead of a vector of written filenames. But at this step the layer names are lost too because `gdalbuildvrt` does not preserve the names.

So this is the workarounds you could use

#### Rename manually

```r
attrnames = c("zmax", "zmean", "zsd", "zskew", "zkurt", "zentropy", "pzabovezmean", "pzabove2", "zq5", "zq10", "zq15", "zq20", "zq25", "zq30", "zq35", "zq40", "zq45", "zq50", "zq55", "zq60", "zq65", "zq70", "zq75", "zq80", "zq85", "zq90", "zq95", "zpcum1", "zpcum2", "zpcum3", "zpcum4", "zpcum5", "zpcum6", "zpcum7", "zpcum8", "zpcum9")
names(get_metrics) <- attrnames
```

#### Change the format and retrieve the names

```r
# Change the default format
ctg@output_options$drivers$Raster$param$format <- "raster"
ctg@output_options$drivers$Raster$extension <- ".grd"

# Compute
get_metrics <- grid_metrics(las, .stdmetrics_z, 15)

# Use the first file to read the names
first <- brick("C:/JAIME/00_tests/test2/firstfilename_metrics.grd")

# Rename
names(get_metrics) <- names(first)
```

---

Also please note that the following:

```r
opt_filter(las) <- "-drop_z_below 0 -keep_first"
get_metrics <- grid_metrics(las, .stdmetrics_z, 15.8114)
```

is equivalent but better than:

```r
opt_filter(las) <- "-drop_z_below 0"
get_metrics <- grid_metrics(las, .stdmetrics_z, 15.8114, filter = ~ReturnNumber == 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Renaming it manually worked like a charm by just inserting the scrypt at the end after "get_metrics" command. The other approach I could not make it work  as I am pretty new in R and do not know how to fit it in my code