# R lidR stdmetrics_z

Tags: r, lidr

When using `stdmetrics_z` in the R package `lidR`, it produces 36 bands of metrics. I am unable to find the definition of each of these bands (metrics). In the help it says to view the [wiki page](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/stdmetrics) but there are not 36 metrics listed pertaining to z values. When I view the output tifs in ArcGIS Pro, they are simply sequentially labeled from 1-36 with no additional information.

Comment: Which band you cannot identify? And yes when loading in external software band names are lost. This is because `writeRaster` does not write the names in GeoTiff files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763013/r-write-rasterstack-and-preserve-layer-names https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/347091/103469

Comment: I can't tell how any of the 36 bands are actually computed. If the wiki page defined each of the 36 metrics (bands) computed by stdmetrics_z, that would be helpful.

Comment: It defines them all but some are grouped such as `zqx` which documents zq5 zq10 zq20 zq30 and so on