# Overwriting files in function pixel_metrics()

Tags: r, lidr

I'm trying to test my pixel_metrics() custom function, and I'm not sure how to overwrite the old file, like the error message suggests in the screenshot. I have added `overwrite=TRUE` to my function call, but it doesn't seem to be working.

It seems like internally pixel_metrics() is calling writeRaster() -- maybe there is a way to propagate `overwrite=TRUE` to writeRaster() ?

Function call:

```
canopy_metrics = pixel_metrics(norm, ~lcp_pixel_metrics(Z, ReturnNumber), 16.4042, overwrite=TRUE)
```

Error message:

> r: [writeRaster] file exists. You can use 'overwrite=TRUE' to
> overwrite it

In addition, I've tried running the following line of code, inspired by [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/325369/227379).

```
canopy_metrics@output_options$drivers$Raster$param$overwrite <- TRUE
```

But R says that "output_options" does not exist for class "SpatRaster."

Comment: I can't see anything in the help or examples about writing to a file, and I can't trigger this error from the examples, but maybe the examples are small data that can work in memory and not need to work with on-disk data... Try `debug(writeRaster)` and then see how its being called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `canopy_metrics@output_options$drivers$Raster$param$overwrite <- TRUE` is correct for `RasterLayer` from the package `raster` but applies to a `LAScatalog`. Here the default output is a `SpatRaster` from `terra`. use:

`norm@output_options$drivers$SpatRaster$param$overwrite <- TRUE`

Comment: I ran `canopy_metrics@output_options$drivers$SpatRaster$param$overwrite <- TRUE` and got the error: `no slot of name "output_options" for this object of class "SpatRaster"`. Do you have any advice?

Comment: See my edit. This applies to a `LAScatalog`