# LidR error "Error: [writeRaster] file exists. You can use 'overwrite=TRUE' to overwrite it" when rasterising canopy height model

Tags: r, lidr, terra

I am currently using the LidR package to rasterize a canopy height model from a LAScatalog object:

```
opt_output_files(ctg_norm) <-  paste0("C:/Programming/C_Forstenried/las_outputs/temp/{*}chm")
chm1 <- rasterize_canopy(ctg_norm, res = 0.5, algorithm = p2r(), overwrite =TRUE)
chm2 <- rasterize_canopy(ctg_norm, res = 0.25, algorithm = p2r(subcircle = 0.15), overwrite = TRUE)
```

However, on the second run, I am stopped by the following error:

`Error: [writeRaster] file exists. You can use 'overwrite=TRUE' to overwrite it`

Has anyone else encountered this problem? I found this (fairly old) forum post: [Configuring lidR catalog to overwrite raster output (with different extension)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325367/configuring-lidr-catalog-to-overwrite-raster-output-with-different-extension/325369#325369), but it did not help. I tried adding overwrites to the terra and raster packages:

```
library(terra)
options(overwrite = TRUE)
library(raster)
rasterOptions(overwrite = TRUE)
```

and added the `overwrite = TRUE` parameter to the `rasterize_canopy` function. I also tried adding this line from the aforementioned forum post:

```
ctg_norm@output_options$drivers$Raster$param$overwrite <- TRUE
```

but to no avail. When I manually change the output file path, it works again, but overwriting would be much more convenient.

Any ideas? I am fairly new to coding...